# Automatic random typing and scrumble

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my first question here, im pretty new and cant solve this by myself!
(also doesnt speak english, sorry ill do my best explaining)

what im trying to achieve is a random text like "XYZXYZXYXZYZYYZYYZZ" with a typewriting effect. thats done, but now i want the text keep randomizing. each character showing up, changes after 1 or 2 seconds(doesnt matter).

the script ive made creates span's with the random character inside, one next to each other, getting the writing effect.
the idea was with another script, change the span content trough their Classes, but doesnt work, the only thing that works is change it by the Id, and of course only changes the first one.

any ideas how to solve this?

http://jsbin.com/ozoTis/1/edit

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Using the same "id" over and over again is wrong. The value of an "id" has to be unique on the page.

Comment: Please, make a jsfiddle from your code that does not work.

Comment: [link](http://jsbin.com/ozoTis/1/edit) here !

Answer (score 0):

You can change the contents of each `<span>` using `document.getElementsByClassName` and `Array.prototype.forEach` functions:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("news"),function(span){
    span.innerHTML="Content";
});
```

Comment: i didt know this, but doesnt solve the random problem, now i have a different problem, http://jsbin.com/IQuxevu/4/edit < this crashes live